# C# 4.0 Allow projects to not care about reference version

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, reference, dll

I have a C# solution with about 10-15 projects. All but one of the projects are DLLs that are about 100-200 KB in size. I want to be able to push out hot fixes by replacing the changed DLLs instead of needing all the DLLs and the EXE to be downloaded for the hot fix. The problem with this is all my references are project references and not by DLL.

How do I tell my project references to be non-version specific?

If you don't feel I should be doing this I understand both sides but please only post an answer on how to do this and not why I shouldn't or should.

Thank You.

Comment: I think the "preferred" method might be to use manifests and redirects ..

Comment: Are your assemblies strong name signed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edit the csproj file directly and add

```
<SpecificVersion>false</SpecificVersion>
```

to the project references.

Comment: @KenWhite: Of course, I should know better than that. Thanks!